# What does the bond issuer/company do when the bond is oversubscribed?

Tags: bonds, government-bonds

I'm a beginner,
I see sometimes in news that a company issue bonds (1 million total issuance), but they received 3 million requests, what will they do with the two million excess ?

Comment: If not mistaken, this is called "oversubscription".

Comment: @Flux you are right, my question should be ..oversubscription exeeds the total issuance, or there is a better editing?

Comment: e.g. "What happens when a bond is oversubscribed?"

Comment: They normally tell you on the subscription form what alternatives they can choose from.